# Customizing the selector icon

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm developing iOs with GeneXus. When I use combos, selectors and pickers, the default selector icon is a "i" symbol inside the control.

Is there any way of customizing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the iOS Theme, in the Application theme class, there are two properties:

- Prompt Image
- Date Picker Image

They are set to "(none)" by default and use the platform icon, but you can use your own custom images.